# Insert values line by line in a JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to write new fields and their values to an existing JSON object using Python, line by line, but it keeps creating another key instead. Here is a sample code :

```
# my object
data_set = {'fruits':[]}

fruit_state = 'eatable'

# the values i want to insert line by line into the same JSON object
data_set['fruits'].append({'apple' : fruit_state})
data_set['fruits'].append({'strawberry' : fruit_state})
data_set['fruits'].append({'lemon' : fruit_state})

json_dump = json.dumps(data_set, indent=4)
print(json_dump)

quit()
```

Which gives me :

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "apple": "eatable"
        },
        {
            "strawberry": "eatable"
        },
        {
            "lemon": "eatable"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm trying to get something so the result would be :

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "apple": "eatable",
            "strawberry": "eatable",
            "lemon": "eatable"
        }
    ]
}
```

I could put every value in an array and pass it, but I really want to insert the values line by line. Would you have an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually want `fruits` to be a list containing a single dictionary? It would make more sense for it to just be a dictionary directly, i.e. `{"fruits": {"apple": ..etc..} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `dict.update`:

```
data_set['fruits'].append({})
data_set['fruits'][0].update({'apple' : fruit_state})
data_set['fruits'][0].update({'strawberry' : fruit_state})
data_set['fruits'][0].update({'lemon' : fruit_state})
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I see I needed to create the list first then update it with the values using its position. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'd be better served with `fruits` holding the sub-object directly, instead of containing a list. Then you can just assign values directly:

```
data_set = {'fruits': {}}
data_set['fruits']['apple'] = fruit_state
data_set['fruits']['strawberry'] = fruit_state
data_set['fruits']['lemon'] = fruit_state
```

Comment: This was my immediate thought. Adding redundant intermediate `list`s into JSON is a pet peeve of mine. All it does is force the consumer to add a `[0]` when parsing.

Comment: That method could be helpful too. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
data_set = {'fruits':[{}]} 
data_set['fruits'][0]['apple'] = fruit_state
data_set['fruits'][0].update({'strawberry' : fruit_state})

json_dump = json.dumps(data_set, indent=4)
print(json_dump)

{
    "fruits": {
        "apple": "eatable",
        "strawberry": "eatable"
    }
}
```